# What is OTB (one touch backup) on SATA HDD Enclosures?

Tags: external-hard-drive

What is OTB (one touch backup) on SATA HDD Enclosures? And how does it work?

Many external HDD enclosures feature the OTB functionality, which I hear is a one-button to backup system to hard-drive. Yet I’m skeptical.

So what is it really and how does it work? And is this platform dependent (e.g. supposed to work with Windows only, or with Linux too)?

Answer (score 4):

You have to install Backup software for OTB to work, the software detects you pushed the button and backs up your system to the usb drive, no magic, just software.

Backup Software is usually on the usb drive itself when purchased new, but has to be installed and configured on the PC you wish to backup.

Typically this software is for Windows or Mac.

[Example](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/203131en)

Comment: So if an HDD enclosure has OTB button, but the software is not installed (e.g. freshly formatted HDD), then pressing the OTB button will not trigger anything, correct?

Comment: Correct, that would be a huge Windows security flaw if it did.

Answer (score 1):

I have a SATA HDD USB 3.0 enclosure for 2 drives.
When I put 2 drives in, without connecting it to a computer, pressing the OTB button clones drive 1 to drive 2.

Comment: That seems like a really dangerous feature for data loss.